# Ultrabook with dual screen

Tags: multiple-monitors, ultrabook

Looking at purchasing a Ultrabook but would like to connect 2 screens to it if possible.

The machine has 1 x mini-HDMI & 1 x mini-VGA and the resolution of the Ultrabook is 1600 x 900 pixels.

Anyway I could configure dual screen on it and have the same quality and resolution image on both screens?

This is the machine: UX31E-RY010V

Comment: According to this post, you can connect two monitors at the same time. I'd be wary about what resolution you can operate them at though.

http://forum.notebookreview.com/8477517-post310.html

Answer (score 1):

Most laptop graphics cards can only drive one external monitor even if there are several connectors.

You may want to consider adding a USB-based graphics card.  DisplayLink has some nice options, both as single cards and also as docking stations including video.  See http://www.displaylink.com/shop/index.php

Answer (score 0):

It depends largely on what the graphics device in your laptop supports.

I have seen laptops that will quite happily drive two external monitors as long as you did not mind disabling the laptop screen itself. Otherwise you could have any combination of laptop screen + 1 external monitor.  I would expect almost all laptops with two display outputs to support this.

I would surprised if any laptop made in the last 3 years could not do this in fact, though older laptops may have a problem.